Thriller about a pregnant woman having visions of the future and her death
There's this movie I remember watching a while back on Netflix, but I can't remember the name of it. 
So basically the main character is a pregnant lady and she's been seeing things like things moving and I think she sees shadows at one point but I don't know for sure. 
I also remember her standing at the sink and taking a pill and she's looking at her reflection in the window. So she starts going to a yoga class I think it is and she meets a girl and they become friends and she vents to this girl about the strange things happening in her house and how basically everyone thinks she's kind of losing it. 
And then at the end of the movie the lady she met and maybe her boyfriend or husband? Goes to the main lady's house. And there's a fight I think it was because she wants the baby because she had lost hers or she can't get pregnant or something. 
And as the fight is going on the pregnant lady realizes that what she has been seeing over the course of the movie is what is happening during the fight. For example a gun I think gets kicked or thrown across the floor and she had seen that before it all happened. 
And I think the explanation for it was that the house was showing how they died or something.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give?Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Possibly Visions from 2015, which can be watched on Netflix.
SPOILER WARNING!
It's about a pregnant woman named Eveleigh (played by Isla Fisher, also known for example from Now you see me) living in a haunted house, that gives her visions of future events. She meets a female friend called Sadie (played by Gillian Jacobs) at a yoga class, who lost her child in a car crash. Together with her husband Ben (played by Bryce Johnson), Sadie later attacks Eveleigh in the haunted house.
See also wikipedia for plot synopsis.
